# MariaDB/MySQL using update inner Join MariaDB is wrong order but correct in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb

Would like to seek your help on below:

I want to update the `lessonnumber` in Table `lessons`, the logic is `lessonnumber` will be update listed by order based on the `starttime`. My laravel code below works in MySQL, but error order occurred in MariaDB.

```
php
DB::statement('set @i=0;');
$type_id = 2;   //lessons type
    
DB::update("
    UPDATE lessons A 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE lessons.type_id = $type_id ORDER BY lessons.starttime ASC LIMIT 30) B
    ON  B.id = A.id
    SET A.lessonnumber = (select @i:=@i+1)
");
```

| id | lessonnumber | startime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | 33 |
| 3 | 2 | 22 |
| 4 | 4 | 44 |
| 5 | 5 | 55 |

Mysql: lessonnumber  1 3 2 4 5  is correct order

| id | lessonnumber | startime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 2 | 33 |
| 3 | 3 | 22 |
| 4 | 4 | 44 |
| 5 | 5 | 55 |

MariaDB: lessonnumber 1 2 3 4 5  is error order

Can anyone help to solve my problem? Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What version of mariadb are you on?

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @P.Salmon MariaDB version 10.3.27, Helps a lot, thanks

Comment: You don't need to use sub-query with your INNER JOIN. If order is important you need to reverse the join or at least put your order clause at the main query level.

Comment: Using @ variables, even if correct today, is likely to be incorrect tomorrow.  You must switch to windowing functions in MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2 in order to get predictable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining on id so the ordering in the join query is ignored. The correct form of update with order by is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

```
SET @I = 0;
UPDATE LESSONS A 
    SET A.lessonnumber = (select @i:=@i+1)
WHERE TYPE_ID = 2
ORDER BY STARTTIME;
```

Comment: This really works!! Helps a lot, thanks so much!